# Understanding Collections in Magento

Tags: magento2, collection

I am new to magento . I am directly learning Magento 2 .Here I created a Collection class inside Model for a custom module as I got a tutorial on internet.

**What is this collection ?** How does it work?
Can anyone explain me this in detail.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to quote the Magento documentation to help you understand the concept of collections:

> Originally, as a PHP programmer, if you wanted to collect together a
>   group of related variables you had one choice, the venerable [Array](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).
>   While it shares a name with C's array of memory addresses, a PHP array
>   is a general purpose dictionary like object combined with the
>   behaviors of a numerically indexed mutable array.
>
> In other languages the choice isn't so simple. You have [multiple data
>   structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_structures#Linear_data_structures) to chose from, each offering particular advantages in
>   storage, speed and semantics. The PHP philosophy was to remove this
>   choice from the client programmer and give them one useful data
>   structure that was "good enough".
>
> All of this is galling to a certain type of software developer, and
>   PHP 5 set out to change the status quo by offering built-in classes
>   and interfaces that allow you to create your own data structures.

```
$array = new ArrayObject(); 
class MyCollection extends ArrayObject{...} 
$collection = new MyCollection(); 
$collection[] = 'bar';
```

> While this is still galling to a certain type of software
>   developer, as you don't have access to low level implementation
>   details, you do have the ability to create array-like Objects with
>   methods that encapsulate specific functionality. You can also setup
>   rules to offer a level of type safety by only allowing certain kinds
>   of Objects into your Collection.
>
> It should come as no surprise that Magento offers you a number of
>   these Collections. In fact, every Model object that follows the
>   Magento interfaces gets a Collection type for free. Understanding how
>   these Collections work is a key part to being an effective Magento
>   programmer.

On top of that I suggest you read [Alan Storm's article about CRUD in M2](http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_crud_models_for_database_access)

Comment: But I didn't find any code in Collections file inside my custom module to fetch all data.Then how data is fetched?